# Validator and Struts not view the error

Tags: java, validation, struts-1, struts-validation

i am studing the Struts Framework and i am trying a example where i use the DynaValidatorForm. In my test, i try to add a "required" chek on the codProdotto field . But It is not shown the error message if i leave blank the text box.

**Form:**

```
  <html:form action="/form_remove_prodotto">
    <span>ID Prodotto</span>
    <html:text property="codProdotto"></html:text><br>
    <html:hidden property="remove" value="removeProduct"/>
    <html:submit title="Elimina Articolo"></html:submit>    


     <br><span style="color:red"><html:errors /></span>
  </html:form>
</body>
```

**struts-config**

```
    <form-bean name="new_product" type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm" >
        <form-property name="codProdotto" type="java.lang.String" />
        <form-property name="descrizione" type="java.lang.String" />
        <form-property name="categoria" type="java.lang.String" />
        <form-property name="numListino" type="java.lang.String" />
        <form-property name="prezzo" type="java.lang.Double" />
        <form-property name="noteAggiuntive" type="java.lang.String" />
    </form-bean>
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>
<action
        attribute="new_product"
        path="/form_remove_prodotto"
        type="controller.ProductManager"
        parameter="removeProduct"
        name="new_product"
        scope="request"
        validate="false"
        input="input.jsp">
        <forward name="ret_index" path="/index.jsp" />
    </action>
 </action-mappings>

<message-resources parameter="MessageResources" />

<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
<set-property
    property="pathnames"
    value="/org/apache/struts/validator/validator-rules.xml,
           /WEB-INF/validation.xml"/>
</plug-in>
```

**Validator**

```
<formset>

    <!-- An example form -->
    <form name="new_product">
        <field 
            property="codProdotto" depends="required">
            <arg key="errors.required" />

        </field>

    </form>

</formset>




</form-validation>
```

** Action **

```
public class ProductManager extends MappingDispatchAction {

public ActionForward addProduct(ActionMapping arg0, ActionForm arg1,
        HttpServletRequest arg2, HttpServletResponse arg3) throws Exception {

    DynaValidatorForm  actionForm = (DynaValidatorForm ) arg1;

    System.out.println("Add");
    return arg0.findForward("ret_index");
}

public ActionForward removeProduct(ActionMapping arg0, ActionForm arg1,
        HttpServletRequest arg2, HttpServletResponse arg3) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DynaValidatorForm  actionForm = (DynaValidatorForm ) arg1;
    System.out.println("Remove " + actionForm.get("codProdotto"));
    return arg0.findForward("ret_index");
}

}
```

Properties File

```
# -- validator --
errors.invalid={0} is invalid.
errors.maxlength={0} can not be greater than {1} characters.
errors.minlength={0} can not be less than {1} characters.
errors.range={0} is not in the range {1} through {2}.
errors.required={0} is required.
errors.byte={0} must be an byte.
errors.date={0} is not a date.
errors.double={0} must be an double.
errors.float={0} must be an float.
errors.integer={0} must be an integer.
errors.long={0} must be an long.
errors.short={0} must be an short.
errors.creditcard={0} is not a valid credit card number.
errors.email={0} is an invalid e-mail address.
```

Comment: Have u checked whether `Properties file` contains value for the key `errors.required` like this : `errors.required = Enter blah`

Comment: Try this `<field property="codProdotto" depends="required">
 
    <msg name="required" key="errors.required" /></field>`

Comment: nothing...I tried to change as you said, but nothin, no see the message

Comment: `i am studing the Struts Framework` - if you're not learning Struts in order to be able to support a legacy app, I'd strongly recommend looking at another framework. Struts 1 reached its end-of-life years ago, and support documents are disappearing. Starting a new project with a dead framework is a bad idea.